# Stop all other <audio> onclick? (also some FontAwesome stuff)

Tags: javascript, html, audio, playback

Long-time lurker, first-time question-asker; my thanks to SO for all its help so far!

**What I want**:
User clicks on one of thirty-ish buttons and hears the appropriate audio track. Clicking on another button plays another track, and stops any already-playing track. Super simple.

**What happens**:
Bugger all.

I'm also changing a play/pause FontAwesome class (which also doesn't work) but I'll figure that one out later:

```
<audio id="song1"><source src="sample/1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="song2"><source src="sample/2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="song3"><source src="sample/3.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>

<button onclick="letsBoogie(song1);"><i class="fa fa-play-circle"></i></button>
<button onclick="letsBoogie(song2);"><i class="fa fa-play-circle"></i></button>
<button onclick="letsBoogie(song3);"><i class="fa fa-play-circle"></i></button>

<script>
var setList = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');

function letsBoogie(sample);
for(var i = 0, len = setList.length; i < len;i++){
    if(setList[i] != sample.target){
        setList[i].pause();
        setList[i].currentTime = 0;
        $(this).find('i').className = "fa fa-play-circle";
    } else {
    setList[i].play();
    $(this).find('i').className = "fa fa-pause-circle-o";
    }
}
}, true);
</script>
```

I've been tearing my hair out over this for days. Any help would be super-duper appreciated.

---

EDIT: For anyone who stumbles on this, here's the final working code. First, identify all audio:

```
<!-- this can be anywhere in body -->
<audio id="song1"><source src="sample/1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="song2"><source src="sample/2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<audio id="song3"><source src="sample/3.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
...
```

Then place your icons (or buttons or links or whatever):

```
<i class="fa fa-play-circle" onclick="letsBoogie(song1,this)"></i>
<i class="fa fa-play-circle" onclick="letsBoogie(song2,this)"></i>
<i class="fa fa-play-circle" onclick="letsBoogie(song3,this)"></i>
...
```

Finally, shove this beauty in your JS:

```
var setList = $('audio');
function letsBoogie(tune, that) {
  if (tune.paused) {
  $.each(setList, function(index, alltunes) { // pause and reset all audio
    alltunes.pause();
    alltunes.currentTime = 0;
  });
    tune.play(); // then toggle play/pause targeted audio
  } else {
    tune.pause();
}
  tune.onplaying = function() { // change icon if playing
  $(that).attr('class', 'fa fa-pause-circle-o');
  }
  tune.onpause = function() { // change icon and reset if paused
  $(that).attr('class', 'fa fa-play-circle');
  sample.currentTime = 0;
  }
  tune.onended = function() { // change icon when finished
  $(that).attr('class', 'fa fa-play-circle');
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You need to `.attr('class',` to set the class than `className` as it is method of `DOM` api.

Try this:

```js
var setList = $('audio');

function letsBoogie(sample, that) {
  $.each(setList, function(index, elem) {
    elem.pause();
    elem.currentTime = 0;
  });
  $('button i').attr('class', 'fa fa-play-circle');
  sample.play();
  $(that).find('i').attr('class', 'fa fa-pause-circle');
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<audio id="song1">
  <source src="sample/1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    <source src="sample/1.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
<audio id="song2">
  <source src="sample/2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    <source src="sample/2.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
<audio id="song3">
  <source src="sample/3.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    <source src="sample/3.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>

<ul>
  <li>Song 1</li>
  <li>
    <button onclick="letsBoogie(song1,this);"><i class="fa fa-play-circle"></i>
    </button>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Song 2</li>
  <li>
    <button onclick="letsBoogie(song2,this);"><i class="fa fa-play-circle"></i>
    </button>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Song 3</li>
  <li>
    <button onclick="letsBoogie(song3,this);"><i class="fa fa-play-circle"></i>
    </button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Edit:** I suggest you not to pass `id` attribute values as arguments(without quotes(`"`)) as JavaScript will look for global variables having name as mentioned argument. If you have any other global variable having same name then your code will not work as expected. I will also suggest using JavaScript event binding than `inline` event binding.

Comment: Thanks so much Rayon - works like a dream. In my naivety, thought that same-value arguments would magically reference each other somehow. Thanks again!